# How to add add icons and Intents in the QuickContactBadge menu for my android program?

Tags: android, icons, contacts, badge

I'm a writing a program to add a new way of communication such as MMS/SMS or SIP phone to Android.

Is there a way to add an icon in the QuickContactBadge menu, when clicking on a contact photo in the Contacts application ?

I wasn't able to fully understand how it works from android sources ... Is the list of icons only populated from mime types found in contacts datas ?

Thanks,

Laurent

Comment: I would like to know the answer. But, I suspect that the API is not available yet. It might be in the next release may be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is based on mime type in the contact.

> The QuickContact list is built from
>   the MIME-types associated with the
>   contacts Data records, so as far as I
>   know there’s no way for your app to
>   appear in the QC list without having
>   added a record to the data table using
>   a sync provider....
>
> -Sam Steele

from the comments [here](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/).

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source project that let's you implement your own QuickActionBar, take a look: http://code.google.com/p/devoquickaction/

It's look very much like the native one. Just in case working with or adding mime types is not what you have in mind and you'd want to add your entirely individual icon/action set to a contact.

Comment: Thanks! But what I wanted to do is making those icons in the QuickContactBadge available from stock android applications.

Comment: In that case, see aprock's reply below - it's correct. Follow the link he posted.