# Register a own handler in Contacts (or extend given ones)

Tags: android

I need some help for a little problem in my little Android-Test program. ;) 
Is it possible in Android to extend the little popup by a long click on contact by an own icon/handler? My target is to click on the new icon and give my intent the contactId and with that I want to go further like this. Here is a little example what I mean:

http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/3550/unbenanntmrp.jpg

If this isn't possible than how can the given handler extended. In my case a click on the message handler (the 2nd one in screenshot) should popup a possibility to open my program. I know this is possible and I searched around a little bit, but I can't find a solution. Maybe you can give me a direction to the right way.

The 3rd and the last question is if it is also possible to extend the Send-Button in the dialogues view of android. I mean if someone sends you a text you can answer directly in this dialogue without calling the message-app. I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance,
tommyboy66

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add add icons and Intents in the QuickContactBadge menu for my android program ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834868/how-to-add-add-icons-and-intents-in-the-quickcontactbadge-menu-for-my-android-pro)

Comment: @feedley:then merge this one with the old

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems that is a really circuitous solution to implement this little behaviour. I think its easier to implement an option to the message handler (my 2nd question). So, did you have a solution for that?